# Add Different Style to list tag using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

Is there any ways to add different style class to all li in a ul tag using jquery/javascript/php.
Consider  I have a list as follows

```
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li><li>d</li><li>e</li></ul>
```

I would like to add as follows

```
<ul><li class='cat1'>a</li><li class='cat2'>b</li><li class='cat3'>c</li><li class='cat4'>d</li><li class='cat5'>e</li></ul>
```

Comment: You would need to assign an Id to each element and have a class associated with that Id. IT would be good to know if this task can be done programmaticaly.

Answer (score 5):

As simple as:

```
$('ul').children('li').addClass(function (i) {
    return 'cat' + (i+1);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: +1 best solution of those offered here. I didn't know `addClass()` can take a function argument, but this makes sense absolutely.

Comment: @Tomalak - If dealing with a large number of elements though and you're just *setting* the class (e.g. you *know* there aren't any previously), then it's far less efficient, so something to keep in mind when choosing.

Comment: @Tomalak It's new in 1.4. A lot of the functions now accept function arguments

Comment: @Nick: Why is that? (primarily I was referring to explicitly calling `children()` instead of selecting `"ul li"` - specific and less error prone) -- @Yi: Ah I see, my knowledge obviously was from earlier versions. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Tomalak - For the selector bit you can do `ul > li` :) I was talking about the `addClass` part ;)

Comment: @Nick: The `>` would be the same result, yes. Knowing it is one thing, thinking of it, another. :) I was referring to `addClass` as well - why would that be "far less" efficient in this context?

Comment: @Tomalak - `.addClass()` takes the existing `class` attribute, splits it, loops though, checking if it's set then combining and adding them back, `.attr()` just checks node type, node name (for special attributes) then calls `setAttribute`, much faster overall and *way* faster in browsers that inline the script (most tracing engines now).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *set* the class, the cheaper way to do it is by using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and the index in its setter function, like this:

```
$("ul li").attr("class", function(i) {
  return "cat" + (i+1);
});
```

If you aren't setting it and just **adding**, use `.addClass(function(i)` instead of `.attr("class", function(i)`.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Thanks :) I tried to clarify why I'm doing this as opposed to `.addClass()` (given the question), as there is a tremendous performance difference, hopefully that clarifies it a bit?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').children('li').each(function(i,v){
   $(this).addClass('cat'+(i+1));
});
```